# Bitcoin-qt Show Transaction Details

Tags: bitcoin-core, api

When looking at the details of a transaction (Show Transaction Details), the From: field is always set to 'unknown'.
Is it possible to add a 'From' parameter to the API so some meaningful description can be sent with the transaction? A 50 text character would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bip 70](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0070.mediawiki) This BIP describes a protocol for communication between a merchant and their customer, enabling both a better customer experience and better security against man-in-the-middle attacks on the payment process.

On of the key features of this proposal is:

> PaymentRequests include a user-friendly description of what the
>   payment is for

Will hopefully be released with Bitcoin-Qt 0.9